# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata' on npx react-native run-android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, build.gradle

I have tried to change compileSdkVersion = 30 and targetSdkVersion = 30 but still no use it is giving the same error again and again also I clean the Gradle but still no use, so if you can help, please help me. This error is been coming for almost 3 to 4 days from today, before that my project was running obviously fine. I also tried cleaning gradel but still no use.

This is the error body I am getting Error body:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
   > One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values:
     The minCompileSdk (33) specified in a
     dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
     is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-31).
     Dependency: androidx.browser:browser:1.5.0-alpha01.
     AAR metadata file: C:\Users\hp\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\a7a45c1d439f263d5595caa518b0e64b\transformed\browser-1.5.0-alpha01\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 50s
```

my android/build.gradle:

````
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31

        if (System.properties['os.arch'] == "aarch64") {
            // For M1 Users we need to use the NDK 24 which added support for aarch64
            ndkVersion = "24.0.8215888"
        } else {
            // Otherwise we default to the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
            ndkVersion = "22.0.7026061"
        }
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:4.1.2")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        mavenCentral {
            // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
            // older versions over there.
            content {
                excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
        }
        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}```
please do help if you can thank you.
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what i did to solve it. The project was on `RN-0.66.4` (I upgraded it to the recent version RN-0.70.4)

- Then in `android/build.gradle` I updated `compileSdkVersion` from 31 to 33.

[This is my configurations for build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXnCA.png)

I hope it helps.